# Как написать свою собственную метафункцию для SFINAE

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

у меня есть следующий код:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
struct is_size_type_more_than
{
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(T) > SIZE;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
struct is_size_type_less_than
{
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(T) < SIZE;
};

...

template<typename T, typename enable_if = void>
class LittleEndian;

using uint16le_t = LittleEndian<std::uint16_t>;
using uint32le_t = LittleEndian<std::uint32_t>;
using uint64le_t = LittleEndian<std::uint64_t>;

using int16le_t = LittleEndian<std::int16_t>;
using int32le_t = LittleEndian<std::int32_t>;
using int64le_t = LittleEndian<std::int64_t>;

template<typename T>
class LittleEndian<T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value && is_size_type_more_than<T, 1u>::value>::type>
{
    ...
};
```

Но когда я хочу использовать этот класс, то получаю следующую ошибку(на самом деле я хотел бы запретить инстанцирование шаблона для нецелочисленных типов данных и для типов данных размер которых меньше двум):

```
template<typename T> 
void some_function(T value)
{
     LittleEndian<T> le_value = value; // Без моей метафункции все исправно работает
     ...
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Error   C2079   'le_value' uses undefined class 'LittleEndian<T,void>'
```

Answer (score 3):

*"на самом деле я хотел бы запретить инстанцирование шаблона для нецелочисленных типов данных и для типов данных размер которых меньше двум"* - В этом коде не видно никакого SFINAE, тут либо инстанцируется вариант `is_integral<T>::value && is_size_type_more_than`, либо ничего. Cоответственно достаточно в тело шаблона добавить соответствующую проверку:

```
template<typename T> class
LittleEndian
{
    static_assert(::std::is_integral<T>::value and (::std::size_t{1} < sizeof(T)));
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

После декларации:

```
template<typename T, typename enable_if = void>
class LittleEndian;
```

при обращении `LittleEndian<std::uint16_t>;` инстанционируется, `LittleEndian<std::uint16_t,void>;`. 
При этом, выражение внутри std::enable_if никогда не принимает тип `void`, т.е. твоя частичная специализация класса никогда не будет востребована.

Решение:

```
template<typename T, 
         typename enable_if = typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value
                                && is_size_type_more_than<T, 1u>::value>::type >
class LittleEndian;
....

template<typename T, typename enable_if>
class LittleEndian
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: После этих действий, конструкция: LittleEndian<T> le_value = value; выдает ошибку: Error C2976 'LittleEndian': too few template arguments

Comment: @QuickDzen Вероятно,  форвард -декларация, в которой обьявлено значение по умолчанию, не видна в точке ` LittleEndian<T> le_value =...` .